# Paint View Zoom with Image not properly zoom : Android

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, zooming

I used canvas  in order to zoom paint view with image including using setImageMatrix(). As shown below class use for zoom and draw line.But problem arised, that is entire screen became to zoom in/out then when i click on paint button i pass one Boolean as false which draw line on touch of finger.but after draw line on image i want to start pinch zoom again with this drawing line on and then i can also zoom in/out with drawing paint but its not going in proper way change x-y of paint view. So If anyone knows this issue, reply plz.

```
public class PaintScreen extends Activity {

    Context mContext;
    private Paint mPaint;
    MaskFilter mEmboss;
    MaskFilter mBlur;
    private LinearLayout mPaintBaseLayout;
    private PaintView mPaintView;

    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix2 = new Matrix();

    private int WIDTH = 0;
    private int HEIGHT = 1;

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int POINT2 = 2;
    static final int ZOOM = 3;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    float newDist;
    float distanceOffset = 50f;
    float minOffset = 50f;
    float maxOffset = 10000f;
    private boolean falg = true;
    private int startval = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_main);

        this.initialize();

        this.PaintSet();

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnzoom);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (falg) {
                    getFlag(false);
                } else {
                    getFlag(true);
                }
            }
        });

        Button btnset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnset);
        btnset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startval = 1;
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialize() {
        mPaintBaseLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.paint_paint_base_layout);

        mContext = this;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaintView = new PaintView(mContext);
        mPaintView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mPaintBaseLayout.addView(mPaintView, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        mPaintBaseLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        mPaintView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        mPaintView.setMPaint(mPaint);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nat);

        mPaintView.setImageBitmap(bm);

        mPaintView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                PaintView view = (PaintView) v;

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (falg) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = DRAG;
                    } else {
                        view.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    if (falg) {
                        oldDist = spacing(event);
                        if (oldDist > 10f) {
                            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(mid, event);
//                           mode = POINT2;
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (falg) {
                        mode = NONE;
                        distanceOffset = minOffset;
                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    if (falg) {
                        mode = NONE;
                        distanceOffset = minOffset;
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (falg) {
                        if (mode == POINT2) {
                            newDist = spacing(event);
                            if (newDist - oldDist > 5f
                                    || newDist - oldDist < -5f) {
                                mode = ZOOM;
                            } else {
                                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                mode = DRAG;

                            }
                        } else if (mode == DRAG) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                    event.getY() - start.y);

                        } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                            newDist = spacing(event);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {
                                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        view.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
                    break;
                }

//              if (startval == 1) {
                    view.cMatrix(matrix);
//              }
                view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                matrixTurning(matrix, view);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean getFlag(boolean b) {
        return falg = b;
    }

    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private static float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
    private static void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    private void matrixTurning(Matrix matrix, ImageView view) {

        float[] value = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(value);
        float[] savedValue = new float[9];
        savedMatrix2.getValues(savedValue);

        // view size
        int width = view.getWidth();
        int height = view.getHeight();

        // image size
        Drawable d = view.getDrawable();
        if (d == null)
            return;
        int imageWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int imageHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int scaleWidth = (int) (imageWidth * value[0]);
        int scaleHeight = (int) (imageHeight * value[0]);

        if (value[2] < width - scaleWidth)
            value[2] = width - scaleWidth;
        if (value[5] < height - scaleHeight)
            value[5] = height - scaleHeight;
        if (value[2] > 0)
            value[2] = 0;
        if (value[5] > 0)
            value[5] = 0;

        if (value[0] > 10 || value[4] > 10) {
            value[0] = savedValue[0];
            value[4] = savedValue[4];
            value[2] = savedValue[2];
            value[5] = savedValue[5];
        }

        if (imageWidth > width || imageHeight > height) {

            if (scaleWidth < width && scaleHeight < height) {
                int target = WIDTH;

                if (imageWidth < imageHeight)
                    target = HEIGHT;

                if (target == WIDTH)
                    value[0] = value[4] = (float) width / imageWidth;
                if (target == HEIGHT)
                    value[0] = value[4] = (float) height / imageHeight;

                scaleWidth = (int) (imageWidth * value[0]);
                scaleHeight = (int) (imageHeight * value[4]);

                if (scaleWidth == width)
                    value[0] = value[4] = (float) width / imageWidth;
                if (scaleHeight == height)
                    value[0] = value[4] = (float) height / imageHeight;
            }

        } else {
            if (value[0] < 1)
                value[0] = 1;
            if (value[4] < 1)
                value[4] = 1;
        }

        scaleWidth = (int) (imageWidth * value[0]);
        scaleHeight = (int) (imageHeight * value[4]);

        if (scaleWidth < width) {
            value[2] = (float) width / 2 - (float) scaleWidth / 2;
        }
        if (scaleHeight < height) {
            value[5] = (float) height / 2 - (float) scaleHeight / 2;
        }

        matrix.setValues(value);
        savedMatrix2.set(matrix);

    }

    public void PaintSet() {

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        // getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(24, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }
}

class PaintView extends ImageView {

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;

    // onDraw
    private Paint mPaint;

    // onTouch
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    public PaintView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1024, 1024, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mCanvas = canvas;
        // canvas = mCanvas;
        Matrix localMatrix = new Matrix();
        localMatrix.setRectToRect(
                new RectF(0.0F, 0.0F, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap
                        .getHeight()),
                new RectF(0.0F, 0.0F, this.mCanvas.getWidth(),
                        this.mCanvas.getHeight()),
                Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, localMatrix, mBitmapPaint);
//      canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
//      canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, PaintScreen.matrix, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    }

    public void setMPaint(Paint paint) {
        mPaint = paint;
    }

    private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        // mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touchUp() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        Log.d("PaintView", "ev ->" + event.getAction());

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchStart(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchMove(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchUp();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void cMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
        mCanvas.setMatrix(matrix);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image with pinch zoom and paint on image

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix1);
                    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix1);
                        midPoint(mid, event);
                        // mode = POINT2;
                        mode = ZOOM;
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    distanceOffset = minOffset;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    distanceOffset = minOffset;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == POINT2) {
                        newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist - oldDist > 5f
                                || newDist - oldDist < -5f) {
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        } else {
                            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                            mode = DRAG;
                        }
                    } else if (mode == DRAG) {
                        matrix1.set(savedMatrix);
                        matrix1.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                event.getY() - start.y);
                    } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist > 10f) {
                            matrix1.set(savedMatrix);
                            float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                            matrix1.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x,
                                    mid.y);
                            finalscale = scale;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }

                view.setImageMatrix(matrix1);
//              matrixTurning(matrix1, view);
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }
        });
    }



mPaintView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                PaintView view = (PaintView) v;
                view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (falg) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = DRAG;
                    } else {
                        view.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    if (falg) {
                        oldDist = spacing(event);
                        if (oldDist > 10f) {
                            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(mid, event);
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (falg) {
                        mode = NONE;
                        distanceOffset = minOffset;
                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    if (falg) {
                        mode = NONE;
                        distanceOffset = minOffset;
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (falg) {
                        if (mode == POINT2) {
                            newDist = spacing(event);
                            if (newDist - oldDist > 5f
                                    || newDist - oldDist < -5f) {
                                mode = ZOOM;
                            } else {
                                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                mode = DRAG;
                            }
                        } else if (mode == DRAG) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                    event.getY() - start.y);
                        } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                            newDist = spacing(event);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {
                                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                finalscale = scale;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        view.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                limitZoom(matrix);
                view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                matrixTurning(matrix, view);
                RectF r = new RectF();
                matrix.mapRect(r);
                scaledImageOffsetX = r.left;
                scaledImageOffsetY = r.top;

                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    private void limitZoom(Matrix m) {

        float[] values = new float[9];
        m.getValues(values);
        float scaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        float scaleY = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
        if(scaleX > MAX_ZOOM) {
            scaleX = MAX_ZOOM;
        } else if(scaleX < MIN_ZOOM) {
            scaleX = MIN_ZOOM;
        }

        if(scaleY > MAX_ZOOM) {
            scaleY = MAX_ZOOM;
        } else if(scaleY < MIN_ZOOM) {
            scaleY = MIN_ZOOM;
        }

        values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] = scaleX;
        values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] = scaleY; 
        m.setValues(values);
    }

    public boolean getFlag(boolean b) {
        return falg = b;
    }
```

**PaintView.class**

```
    class PaintView extends ImageView {

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mBitmapPaint;

// onDraw
private Paint mPaint;

// onTouch
private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

public PaintView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1024, 1024, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mCanvas = canvas;
    // canvas = mCanvas;
     canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    // canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, PaintScreen.matrix, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

}

public void clear() {
    mPaint.reset();
    // invalidate();
}

public void setMPaint(Paint paint) {
    mPaint = paint;
}

private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
    // mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touchUp() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    Log.d("PaintView", "ev ->" + event.getAction());

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touchStart(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touchMove(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touchUp();
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void cMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
    mCanvas.setMatrix(matrix);
}
}
```